# What defines the "interval" when playing back Performance Co-Pilot data in pcp-atop?

Tags: performance-monitoring, rhel7, atop

I have PCP (Performance Co-Pilot) recording performance metrics on a RHEL 7 host. The recording cadence is set to `Y` seconds here:

```
/etc/pcp/pmlogger/control.d/local
```

When I copy the performance metrics logs to another machine I'm able to analyze the files using:

```
pcp atop --interval=Zs -r /path/to/archive/files/
```

(where `Z` is a value that may or may not be the same as `Y`)

When I jump around in the archive using the `t` and `T` commands I move by `Z` seconds, which makes sense.

My question is about the *calculated* values that `pcp atop` displays. According to `man pcp-atop`, values such as CPU utilization percentage and system memory utilization percentage are calculated over the past "`interval`", but it's unclear whether that interval is the *capture* interval or the *display* interval for replayed data.